# Re-cache App.Config

Tags: app-config

Is it posible to re-cache app.config? 
for example after changing some fields in app.config do not restart application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this answer:
[Change connection string & reload app.config at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502411/change-connection-string-reload-app-config-at-run-time)

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh certain sections of the configuration file using the `ConfigurationManager` class so the next time that section needs to be read, it's pulled from disk.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.refreshsection%28VS.80%29.aspx