# How to read and update value in xml file via C sharp?

Tags: c#, xml

I have the xml file is following manner :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Conn" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
       connectionString="Data Source=machine_name; Initial Catalog=database_name; User ID=id; Password=password" />
  </connectionStrings>
     </configuration>
```

In above xml file i want to change the value of password.

Code i have tried is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication85
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"filepath.xml");
            var element = xdoc.Elements("Password").Single();
            element.Value = "new password";
            xdoc.Save(@"filepath.xml");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The XML file you've shown doesn't *have* an element called "Password", does it?

Comment: The password is not an element of the xdoc, but embedded into a string, which is the value of an attribute `connectionString` of the element `add` (child of `connectionStrings`). You'll need to get that child, and get that attribute, and manipulate the password part of the string using string manipulations (could use regex), then reassign the attribute's value.

Comment: Do you want to update the physical config file or just load a new connection string with updated password into use?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to change the application configuration is through the methods of the ConfigurationManager class, not through XmlDocument methods..

See this question:

[Change connection string & reload app.config at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502411/change-connection-string-reload-app-config-at-run-time)