# Why modify my app.config doesnt work?

Tags: c#

Here is my AppConfig File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
    </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Connection" connectionString="(local)\SQLexpress"/>
    <add name="MainPrinter" connectionString=""/>
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

And I want to change MainPrinter's Name

Here is what i'm trying to do:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.AppSettings.Settings["MainPrinter"].Value = "Epson";
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

But i dont take any result

Comment: Don't use AppConfig as a persistence.  You should not be modifying the values in code.  99.9% of the time you should consider it "read only"

Comment: ok is it better to create a txt file?

Comment: No, its better to just set the connection string for MainPrinter and leave it alone.  If you need different values for different environments then you would use Config Transforms

Comment: Can you give me an example? I need my client to change it inside my application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change connection string & reload app.config at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502411/change-connection-string-reload-app-config-at-run-time)